# Docusign JWT application access token fails when creating and sending envelop

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, docusignapi

following docusign documentations I have written code to send and downloaded signed docs from docusign this was done using the OAuth token generator for development provided by docusign, now I am getting application token using `api_client.request_jwt_application_token` which hits /oauth/token end point, I am using the access_token provided by this to create and send envelop but I get the following error

**errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",\r\n  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. invalid_request**

I've tried different solutions but so far nothing worked for me

Comment: It sounds like your headers might be the issue. Can you use a network trace tool such as Fiddler to capture the headers your application is sending to DocuSign, but with the token redacted?

Comment: I'm running this in Vagrant, with linux in it, can you suggest me tool for that? I'll try Fiddler see if that works too

Comment: Nothing I'm familiar with myself, but there are a couple of suggestions over here: https://superuser.com/questions/228011/capture-virtual-machine-traffic-in-fiddler

Comment: it sends it on port 443 and everything is gibberish I'll try to attach the parameters that get sent along with the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things that you must ensure:

1. You have an Integration key (clientID) that is configured correctly.
2. You have an RSA Private key. that key was copied/pasted exactly as given to your configuration file. New lines must be preserved
3. Your URLs are matching the environment. Meaning you use account-d and demo.docusign.net for the sandbox env endpoints.
4. You need the userId which is a GUid for the user that would be impersonated. That user must consent to the application. You have to ensure you pass userId and not accountId and that it is for the same account that you would be using.

If you confirm all of this and still get an error - I would consider to use our code example to start. I don't see code in your question, but our code example should be a good way to start.

Comment: I needed to enforce consent for the user and for that I needed to enable blanket consent for my application for that I had to add TXT token to the DNS entry, after that it worked great for me, and instead of using request_jwt_application_token I reverted back to using request_jwt_user_token.